# Servicenow "Business Rules": What tables allow me to view business rules?

Tags: servicenow

Hopefully an easy one. Which Servicenow table enumerates business rules ?

I seem to have found the scripts (sys_script_include) but I cant find the rules that call them.

-Rich

Answer (score 2):

Business Rules are stored on the **sys_script** table.
sys_script_include is for Script Includes.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I prefer looking at a table in the list view:

On a browser window `https://<address of yourSN instance>/table_name_list.do`

Paginates quicker and handy when the table's really big.

Comment: I've modified the answer. The previous response wasn't intended to be a fixed URL. You'll understand it if you're a ServiceNow user.

Answer (score 0):

sys_script is the table where business rules are stored. 
Pro tip: sys_script.list will open the list. 
sys_script.LIST will open it in a new tab/window.